# How to format numbers in a specific row using js in a table rendered with rhandsontable?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, rhandsontable

In the simplified code at the bottom of this post, I believe it is js that is used for formatting outputs of the table rendered using rhandsontable. I play around with row/column formatting with some success in the js section of the code. However, as illustrated below, how would I format row 2 of the table so that it is shown as an integer (rounded to digits = 0, so there are no decimals) with commas separating the thousands, for all columns as they are added?

I've played around with the usual `formatC()`, etc., with no luck. Looks like the answer might lie in js.

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,2000.39,3,4),check.names = FALSE)

rownames(mydata) <- c('A','B','C','D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      newcol <- data.frame(NROW(mydata))
      newcol[2,] <- c(1234.22)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata,rowHeaderWidth = 100)%>%
      hot_cols(
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
          // format as integers first 2 rows:
            if(row == 0 || row == 1){td.innerHTML = `${value}`;} 
          // shade 2nd row:
            if(row == 1){td.style.background='#eff0f1'} 
          // format as % the 2nd set of 2 rows:
            if(row == 2 || row == 3){td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`} 
        }") %>% 
      hot_row(c(2), readOnly = TRUE) # makes row 2 read-only
    
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the formatter functions provided by the  [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to format your numbers using e.g. `Intl.NumberFormat`. To get a comma as the grouping mark you could use e.g. US locale:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,2000.39,3,4),check.names = FALSE)

rownames(mydata) <- c('A','B','C','D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      newcol <- data.frame(NROW(mydata))
      newcol[2,] <- c(1234.22)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata,rowHeaderWidth = 100)%>%
      hot_cols(
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
          Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
          
          const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            maximumFractionDigits: 0
          })
          
          // format as integers first 2 rows:
            if(row == 0 || row == 1){td.innerHTML = `${value}`;} 
          // shade 2nd row:
            if(row == 1){td.style.background='#eff0f1'} 
          // format as % the 2nd set of 2 rows:
            if(row == 2 || row == 3){td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`} 
          
          // format second row as numbers:
            if(row == 1) { td.innerHTML = `${formatter.format(value)}`;} 
        
         }
      ") %>% 
      hot_row(c(2), readOnly = TRUE) # makes row 2 read-only
    
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: During my searches I saw a lot of people fumbling around for an answer to this without success. Finally, a clear solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

@stefan has a nice answer. My present answer does not provide the desired output but I think it is instructive.

The **rhandsontable** package includes the (old version of the) [**Numbro** library](https://numbrojs.com/index.html). Theoretically one should get the desired output by doing:

```js
// shade and format second row
if(row == 1){
  td.style.background = '#eff0f1';
  td.innerHTML = numbro(value).format('0,0');
}
```

But there's a bug in this version of **Numbro** I think, and this does not display the desired format, there are the decimal digits.

For example if you want one decimal digit: `numbro(value).format('0,0.0')`.

The formatting to percentage works: `numbro(value).format('0%')`.

### Alternative: d3.format

If you want to use a flexible library for number formatting, [**d3-format**](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) is very nice.

This gives the desired output:

```js
// shade and format second row
if(row == 1){
  td.style.background = '#eff0f1';
  td.innerHTML = d3.format(',.0f')(value);
}
```

after including the **d3-format** library in your UI:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-format@3")
  ),
  ......
```